# Ubuntu 20.04 unable to ssh to Cisco IOS

Tags: networking, 20.04, ssh, cisco

Had a Ubuntu 18.x control workstation with the ability to ssh to Cisco network devices. This workstation received an upgrade to 20.04 last evening.  Everything on client side appeared to well but unable to ssh to devices.

Built new Ubuntu 20.04 VM with same results.

**Ubuntu Control Station:**

```
ssh ops@10.1.251.231
Unable to negotiate with 10.1.251.231 port 22: no matching key exchange method found. Their offer: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
```

**Router response:**

```
Oct  4 06:07:10.126: %SSH-3-NO_MATCH: No matching kex algorithm found: client curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,ext-info-c server diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
```

I came across some other documentation which I followed the instructions with no success and the same condition.

By default, when Ubuntu is first installed, remote access via SSH is not allowed. Enabling SSH on Ubuntu is fairly straightforward.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install openssh-server
```

You can verify that SSH is running by typing:
sudo systemctl status ssh

*sudo systemctl status ssh*

**Output:**

```
ssh.service - OpenBSD Secure Shell server
    Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
    Active: active (running) since Mon 2020-06-01 12:34:00 CEST; 9h ago
```

Ubuntu ships with a firewall configuration tool called UFW. If the firewall is enabled on your system, make sure to open the SSH port:

```
sudo ufw allow ssh
```

Looking for a solution to ssh to Cisco IOS.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: hi there, if you are trying to connect with ssh to the cisco ios you do not have to install open-ssh (server) on you ubuntu machine, but you do have to install open-ssh server on the cisco ios if she do not have one. try to log in the webpage of the cisco ios and look for the ssh service and enable it. another option is to run `nmap <cisco-ip>` and look what ports already open (maybe another port that you can set the ssh through him). please post the output of the ports scan.

Comment: SSH is running on the Cisco Routers and Switches.  All was working before the upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04.  As stated, I did build a new 20.04 and received the same out for the attempted SSH connection.  Following that I built a new 18.04 and have no problems with SSH.  The issue is with the cypher and I am looking for someone with topic knowledge to explain and provide a solution for the 20.04 issue.  Thanks everyone.

Comment: seems to be a cisco bug? see https://community.cisco.com/t5/cisco-bug-discussions/cisco-ios-does-not-support-openssh-6-4/td-p/2354553

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu 20.04 deprecated some more insecure algorithms.
To re-enable them you can create a conf file in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/` with the options you need.

For example (based on your router's response):

```
echo "KexAlgorithms diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1" >>/etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/weak.conf
```

Comment: I believe it should be `/etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/weak.conf`

Answer (score 0):

added these 2 lines in ubuntu and it works !

vi /etc/ssh/ssh_config

KexAlgorithms diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1

Ciphers aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc

Answer (score -1):

vi /etc/ssh/ssh_config

KexAlgorithms diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1

Comment: Please add some explanation as to what your code does